While unsaving a question, I get an error message saying "An error occurred"
Since last couple of days, I am facing an error while unsaving a question.
On question, if I try to unsave a question by clicking a bookmark like button below downvote button, it does not work and shows the error "An error occurred".
Earlier I thought this might be something temporary and neglected; but this is consistent.
Saving the question works fine. Unsaving the question from "Saves" tab also works fine.
Another interesting observation is that, if I open a question -> save it -> immediately unsave it. It works.
Also, it seems only with me (or may be very few others), because, I asked about this on SOCVR and no one said they do have this issue.
Steps to reproduce:-

Open a previously saved question from "Saves" tab.
Click the "Save/Unsave" button below "downvote" button.
I get the red popup message saying "An error occurred".

Environment:-

Browser is Chrome latest version
Windows 10 64 bit.
I have created 2 saves lists addition to the default; total 3.



Have you tried this on a question that isn't deleted?

Yes; the non-deleted questions also have same issue @KarlKnechtel.

potential cross site dup of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383530/997587

An error occurred Definitely one of the best, most helpful error messages I have ever read.
